# Rpc payment_queryFeeInfo fails on Westend 9310

Tags: rpc, fee, json-rpc, westend, bug

After the latest upgrade of Westend runtime to version 9310 the RPC call `payment_queryFeeInfo` fails with the following error message:

```json
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":1,"message":"Unable to query dispatch info.","data":"Failed to decode return value of TransactionPaymentApi_query_info"},"id":604352276}
```

However, execution of `state_call` with the following arguments: `["TransactionPaymentApi_query_info", <Encoded extrinsic here>]` successfully completes.

Also we noticed that polkadot-js uses `state_call` for fetching the fee.
Does it mean that `payment_queryFeeInfo` should be considered deprectated? Or is it a bug in the 9310 runtime?

Comment: Generally (this is not the first time this happens), this indicates a mismatch between the node and runtime versions, i.e. the RPC node calls into the runtime and then cannot decode the response. Basically it means that the RPC nodes would need to be upgraded to match the runtime version (or if newer, downgraded).

For the `state_call` question - this doesn't suffer from the same issues (no node <-> runtime encoding), hence the JS API using `api.call.*` to make these queries. Generally if functionality is available on the runtime calls and rpcs, you would rather use the runtime calls.

Comment: Thank you! That explains the issue. If you want, you can move this comment to the `answers` section and I will mark it as accepted one

Comment: Copied the answer and added some (small) clarifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally (this is not the first time this happens), this indicates a mismatch between the node and runtime versions, i.e. the RPC node calls into the runtime and then cannot decode the response.

Basically it means that the RPC nodes would need to be upgraded to match the runtime version (or if newer, downgraded). With this in place the node would be able to decode the responses from the runtime and provide the results over RPC.

For the `state_call` question - this doesn't suffer from the same issues (since there is no node <-> runtime encoding involved), hence the JS API using `api.call.*` to make these payment queries.

Generally if functionality is available on the runtime calls and RPCs, you would rather use the runtime calls.